# Implement second level cache in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, .nettiers, asp.net-caching

Is there any way to use caching in ASP.Net except SQL Server second level cache. As it is the first time to work with caching I want any way with an example.  I have found that NHibernate implements this but we are using .netTiers as an application framework.

Comment: Your question is very vague - are you talking about caching in general or caching of something specific to ASP.Net?  What have you already tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: yes the i have a Facebook application where the user enter some settings then i redirect him to the search result of this settings but every time i reload the settings from the data base with the user id i do not want to do that every time just one time

Comment: You can cache the value in the session. If your indexes are right, the cost of getting it from the database should not be a problem.

Comment: can you explain more because it takes more time when reloading it from the database , and I do not want use session or view statue as i connect also with asp.net mvc application that is why i want to use cashing

Answer (score 1):

The Session cache seems to be the appropriate caching mechanism here. The Session cache is a fault-tolerant cache of objects.

**Inserting an object**

```
Session["Username"] = "Matt";
```

**Reading an object**

```
string username = (string)Session["Username"];
```

**Removing an object**

```
Session.Remove("Username");
```

I say fault-tolerant because if the value with the key you specify doesn't exist in the Session cache, it will not through an exception, it will return null. You need to consider that when implementing your code.

One thing to note, if you are using Sql Server or State Server, the objects you can put in the cache need to be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is also a very good way to go, as it is very flexible. It is a windows service that runs on any number of machines and your app can talk to  the instances to store and retrieve from the cache. [Good Article Here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/07/memcached)